# visitor Id not saved in database

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm building rest API for mobile application and I need to track each visitor for the application, but when I call the api visitor not added to database.

I used the following code:

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
...
)
{
  ...
  $this->session = $session;
  ...
}


public function getVisitorId()
{
$visitor = $this->session->getVisitorData();
print_r($visitor);
}
```

but it always gives me null

So why it's not saved and how to added it

Comment: visitor_id won't work in api calls as it is saved in the db on the basis of  session id.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar so, how should I track the visitor?